# Shaarei Teshuvah by Rabbeinu Yonah online

Tags: hebrew, product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet

Does anyone know where I can find the Hebrew text of שערי תשובה by Rabbeinu Yonah online?

Comment: if you like an answer, consider marking it correct.

Answer (score 4):

[שערי תשובה by Rabbeinu Yonah is available on hebrewbooks.org](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=52774&pgnum=1) You can [download the sefer](http://download.hebrewbooks.org/downloadhandler.ashx?req=52774) there as a PDF for offline viewing as well

Answer (score 3):

The text is also available via [Torat Emet](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/) - you can find an HTML version of the text [here](http://www.ateret4u.com/online/f_01645.html).

In response to activities and comments that took place off this website, I'd like to add that if you look at the top of the page linked above, you'll notice that Torat Emet has claimed a copyright on the text with "כל הזכויות שמורות" (all rights reserved).

Comment: a copyright on a public domain book?

Comment: @ray (note: not legal advice). If you take something public domain and do new creative work on it, creating a derivative work, that derivative work is granted a new copyright. For example a translation of a PD work is always given a new copyright. As an extreme example, in the 90s the Israeli supreme court ruled that simply rotating an image [gave one a copyright](http://tushnet.blogspot.com/2006/11/nimmer-on-dead-sea-scrolls.html) on the dead sea scrolls. Obviously TE thinks they've done enough work to qualify for a new copyright, although how that would hold up is an open question.